# How to check the user already offer the ride using LINQ in NET Core

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Username exceed 15 characters")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }

    }


 public class Vehicle
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Brand { get; set; }


        public string PlateNumber { get; set; }

        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }


        public ICollection<Ride> Rides { get; set; }
    }

public class Ride
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime RideStartTime { get; set; }


        //Relationship 
        //Ride has One Vehicle
        public int VehicleId { get; set; }
        public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

        //Ride has One Vehicle
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public Event Event { get; set; }


    }


// In RideRepository
    public bool IsRideExists(int vehicleId, int eventId )
        {

            return RepositoryContext.Rides.Any(ride => ride.VehicleId.Equals(vehicleId) && ride.EventId.Equals(eventId));
        }
```

> ```
> One to many
> My relationship in ef core
> One user can have many vehicle
> One vehicle has one user
>
> One to many
> One ride can have one vehicle
> one vehicle can have many ride
>
> Many to many
> one ride can have one event
> one event can have one ride
> ```
>
> User can offer ride only with one vehicle per event. 1 event for 1 user.
>   My problem is when i offer ride with another vehicle, the offer ride is successfully entered the database, i want to use LINQ command to check if one vehicle already offer the ride, the user cant offer ride using other car for the same event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your is exist to something in this line, add `userId` in your paramter

```
RepositoryContext.Rides.Any(ride => (ride.VehicleId.Equals(vehicleId) && ride.EventId.Equals(eventId)) || (ride.Vehicle.UserId == userId && ride.EventId.Equals(eventId)));
```

this `|| (ride.Vehicle.UserId == userId && ride.EventId.Equals(eventId))` will check if the user and this event already exists